# Is there a way to maintain the first zero of a number in string, after converting it to an integer?

Tags: c++, string, integer

`atoi()` function will ignore the leading zero of the integer string, when it being converted to integer.

For example,

```
atoi("01234");
```

gives the result `1234`, instead of `01234`.

Is there a way to maintain the `0`, in the result of the string to integer conversion?

Comment: Then do not convert it to an integer first. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: as far as i know computer stores everything in binary...so what does leading zero in int mean ?

Comment: What makes you think a leading zero should be kept in a numeric value? BTW if you have a integer literal like `01234` the numeric value will be 668  in decimal representation.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, this is because I want to reject any input (by default it is in string), which contain the alphabets. So, I think of using this stoi/atoi to convert the input to integer. So that I can detect if the input contains alphabets, by comparing the result of the conversion to the original input (in string), using strncmp(). Since atoi/stoi will not convert any non-integer character or it will stop convert til the location it sees the first non-integer character, if the result of comparison is not the same, then I know the input contains alphabetical characters.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, because I need to handle an input (which by default is a string), the input can be random,so it is possible to start with zero,eg 01234

Comment: @John5012 If you need to handle the input including leading zeros, don't store it as numbers but as `std::string`, that simple.

Comment: A number is a number is a number. A number cannot have a "leading zero". Only a string representation of a number can have a "leading zero", and the operation you are performing literally moves _away_ from string representations. It's very unclear what you're trying to do, and why you chose `atoi` (or `stoi`?) to do it.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone for the advices.

Comment: I think all you need is to use the original value once you perform a check and find out the string meets your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers do not have a leading zero by definition. However, if you must, you can include some code that allows you to determine how many leading zeroes are in the string and then store that into a variable, where you can use it later.